# Visual Studio 2022 removes part of connection string on publish - .NET 7

Tags: entity-framework-core, publish, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

My `appsetting.json` file contains :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Server=localhost;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;encrypt=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 }
```

After migration to .NET 7 and EF Core 7, new default value for `encrypt` is `true`.

But, publishing from Visual Studio removes this `'encrypt=false;'` section from connection string and app can't be run until I manually change the connection string.^

Comment: Sorry, can you explain the exact steps to reproduce it?

Comment: after each publish,there is new file 'appsettings.production.json' in destenation folder.
this file does not exists in original folder, but generated on publish process from 'appsettings.json'. the specific section is missing.

Comment: @mordechai can you please post a full [mre]?

Comment: thanks to @Guru Stron,  on the way for making an short example, I have found the simple value 'DestinationConnectionStrings- default connection' in('xx.pubxml.user') that cause the problem.